# Rails oauth-plugin: multiple strategies causes duplicate nonce error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth, oauth-provider

I have a controller action that may be hit by the client with a 
oauth client token (no authenticated user), or may be hit by an authorized client with an access 
token (for a specific user). I want to set up a nice little before filter to accomodate 
this. I tried:

```
oauthenticate :strategies => [:oauth10_request_token, :oauth10_access_token], 
              :interactive => false, 
              :only => [:wonky_action]
```

If I try to hit this action with an access-token request, then it 
complains because it tries to remember the OauthNonce twice. Here's 
what my ClientApplication.verify_request method looks like:

```
def self.verify_request(request, options = {}, &block) 
    begin 
        signature = OAuth::Signature.build(request, options, &block) 
        nonce = OauthNonce.remember(signature.request.nonce, signature.request.timestamp) 
        unless nonce 
            Rails.logger.warn "Oauth request failing because of invalid nonce." 
            return false 
        end 
        value = signature.verify 
        unless value 
            Rails.logger.warn "Signature verification failed." 
        end 
        value 
    rescue OAuth::Signature::UnknownSignatureMethod => e 
        false 
    end 
end
```

Looking at this, the behavior is no surprise. It runs through the 
oauth10_request_token method, and remembers the nonce without a 
problem, but the token is not a request token, so it fails. Then, it 
tries to run through oauth10_access_token, and when it calls 
verify_request the second time, it tries to remember a nonce that 
we've already remembered.

The best solution I can come up with is to separate the Nonce-remembering from the rest of the request verification. In other words, 
the server would verify the nonce first, and then do the signature 
verification (or whatever else verify_request wants to do) as many 
times as it pleases.

I don't see a clear way to do this without forking Pelle's 
application_controller_methods file, but I'm hoping I'm just missing 
the obvious fix that one of you will suggest! Thanks for your help! 
In case you're interested, I'm using rails3 with pelle's oauth-plugin 
and his fork of oauth:

```
gem 'oauth', :git => "http://github.com/pelle/oauth.git", :require => 'oauth/server' 
gem "oauth-plugin", :git => 'https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

Comment: An unsatisfying way around this is to do the token authentication first, then the two_legged. If you do this with a valid access token, the token succeeds and the nonce won't be checked again. If you do this with just a client token, then an error occurs during the access_token step before nonce remembering (it can't actually build the signature). In the case where you have neither, auth fails, which is what we want but it's dirty.

Actually, this is the default behavior of `oauthenticate`